# Cursorcerer, change delay from terminal

Tags: cursor

I use Cursorcerer to hide my pointer, and find that I cannot turn it off completely unless I set the delay to 0 sec; otherwise it pops up when I change app &c. On the other hand, if I need it, I also need it to change the setting in the præference pane. Can the delay be changed from terminal?

Answer (score 1):

From Terminal, you should be able to do

```
defaults write com.doomlaser.cursorcerer idleHide -float 0
```

and then

```
killall Cursorcerer
~/Library/PreferencePanes/Cursorcerer\ 2.prefpane/Contents/Resources/Cursorcerer.app/Contents/MacOS/Cursorcerer &
```

to quit and relaunch the Cursorcerer daemon with the updated pref